# Vagrant/Puppet Connection Timeout (Obvious Fixes Attempted, Working Previously)

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, puppet, puppetlabs-apache, puphpet

For some reason my Vagrant/Puppet instance stopped working out of the blue--I am no longer able to reach the VM from my host machine, despite no configuration or network changes.

Interestingly, the private network must be recognized as the browser is attempting to connect, however the request seems to be timing out when issued from OSX...  Also worth noting, I have not installed any system updates at this time.  The VM was working previously on 10.9.

Steps I have tried to resolve the issue:

`vagrant destroy && vagrant up`

**Result:** Vagrant loads properly, SSH works and apache is running with the proper result returned from `ping 127.0.0.1`

---

`vagrant reload`

**Result:** Same as above; VM reloads successfully, no change in network accessibility

---

`sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`

**Result:** No change in accessibility via the bound IP (10.0.0.100)

---

Port forwarding (explicit) vs `"private_network"` in vagrant file

**Result:** No change in accessibility via the bound IP (10.0.2.15)

---

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

**Result:** No change in accessibility via the bound IP, connection still times out

---

**Vagrant File:** http://pastebin.com/Hk8drWxF

**Puppet File:** http://pastebin.com/20Sp1m22

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could this be an issue with netmask ? You specify 2 ips there : 10.0.0.100 and 10.0.2.15 if you're using default subnet (class C) you would end up on different subnets and be unable to speak directly to each other.